# Zeroise custom pagination to have leading 0

Tags: pagination

I'm trying to have leading 0's in front of my custom pagination and I've seen that I need to use the [zeroise](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/zeroise/) function to achieve this.

I've tried a few different ways to implement but it just doesn't seem to be making any difference to my *numeric_post_nav* function.

```
//Zeroize
function zeroize_page_numbers( $link, $i ) {
   $zeroised = zeroise( $i, 2 );

   $link = str_replace( $i, $zeroised, $link );

   return $link;
}
add_filter( 'number_post_nav', 'zeroize_page_numbers', 10, 2 );


//Custom Pagination
function numeric_post_nav() {
    if( is_singular() )
        return;
    global $wp_query;
    /* Stop the code if there is only a single page page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );
    /*Add current page into the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;
    /*Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }
    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }
    echo '<ul id="news-pagination">' . "\n";
    

    /*Display Link to first page*/
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );
        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }
    /* Link to current page */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }
    /* Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";
        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }
     echo '</ul>' . "\n";
}
```